# WooCoomerce: Open pop-up upon clicking the terms checkbox

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, woocommerce, checkout

I've started to be a bit desperate here. So I have a check-box in the terms area of my woocommerce checkout to agree that you read our T&C. However, we are offering services that ABSOLUTELY require people to read our terms because they include health hazard information. Obviously, legally we will be fine by offering the terms and having people agree that they read them.

What I want to achieve, though, is that a pop-up opens, when that check-box is clicked. It does not have to be fancy or styled, but since this is in woocommerce I am VERY unsure about where to place what.

A simple `<input type="checkbox" id="xxx">` type and javascript was my first guess, but I do not know where to put what in this case since Woocommerce seems to be a rather closed ecosystem, so neither did I find where to place my JS (too many different phps?) nor where to link the checkbox. I was so lost.

Maybe you guys have a different approach or know where to put what.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi there, any feed back on the answer below will be really appreciated.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The below code will add an additional custom T&C checkbox in the checkout page, before the "place order" button:

```
// Additional terms and conditions check box in checkout page
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_terms_and_conditions', 'add_terms_and_conditions_checkbox', 20 );
function add_terms_and_conditions_checkbox() {

    woocommerce_form_field( 'terms_two', array(
        'type'          => 'checkbox',
        'class'         => array( 'terms terms-two' ),
        'input_class'   => array('woocommerce-form__input-checkbox'),
        'label_class'   => array('woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox'),
        'label'         => '<span>' . sprintf( 
            __( "I have read and accept %s…", $domain ),
            '<a class="terms_link" id="terms_link">'.__( "the terms and conditions", $domain ).'</a>'
        ) . '</span>',
        'required'      => true,
    ), '');
}
```

> Or you can also [override ,via your theme,](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) the template file [`checkout/terms.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/checkout/terms.php) which displays the WooCommerce terms and conditions checkbox on checkout page, to make it as you want.

In the below function you can include the related javascript / jQuery script on checkout page for your pop up opening event:

```
// Auto Show hide checkout shipping fields based on chosen shipping methods
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_checkout_field_script' );
function custom_checkout_field_script() {
    // Only on checkout page
    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ):

    // Jquery code start
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($){
            // Here come your jQuery code
        });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

Related: [European GDPR additional checkout validation checkbox in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49494935/european-gdpr-additional-checkout-validation-checkbox-in-woocommerce/49497361#49497361)